# columncount property cannot be set on a data-bound datagridview control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a code that works when showing record and filter data in a `datagridview`.

ShowRecord code:

```
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSELECTALL", cn)

    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
    dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    dgv1.ColumnCount = 8
    SelectedRows()
    dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
    dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
    dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
    dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
    dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
    dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
    dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
    dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
    dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
    dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
    dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
    dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
    dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
    dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"
    dgv1.Columns(7).Name = "ContactNumber"
    dgv1.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "TelNum"
    dgv1.DataSource = dt

End Using
```

FilterData code:

```
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspYearFilter", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", cboYear.Text)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
    dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
    dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
    dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
    dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SurName"
    dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
    dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FirstName"
    dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
    dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
    dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
    dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
    dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
    dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
    dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
    dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"
    dgv1.Columns(7).Name = "ContactNumber"
    dgv1.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "TelNum"
    dgv1.DataSource = dt
End Using
```

The problem here is when i use the FilterData code and select again the ShowRecord code. It throws an error in this line:

```
dgv1.ColumnCount = 8
```

saying that

> columncount property cannot be set on a data-bound datagridview
>   control

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: remove the datasource?  `dgv1.DataSource = Nothing` seems like an XY problem though

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for your help. Problem solved